# Find by dynamic attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a class to a dynamic attribute, here is what I have :

**HTML**

```
  <button data-filter=".category-1" class="item col-lg-8 col-md-11" style="background:#ea4176;"> Education </button>
  <button data-filter=".category-2" class="item col-lg-8 col-md-11" style="background:#ffc600;"> Technology </button>
```

**JS**

```
     $( "button[data-filter='.category-' + gon.activity]" ).addClass( "is-checked" );
```

`gon.activity` correspond to the number of the category. What is the syntax which I have to use?

Comment: `$( 'button[data-filter=".category-' + gon.activity + '"]' ).addClass( "is-checked" );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to user proper quotes.

See the highlighted changes in below code.

```
$("button[data-filter='.category-" + gon.activity + "']").addClass("is-checked");
//                               ^^^^            ^^^^^
```

You can also use single-quote outside and double-quote inside

```
$('button[data-filter=".category-' + gon.activity + '"]').addClass("is-checked");
//                               ^^^^            ^^^^^
```